# Error while auto populate input field using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am building a simple applicatio in PHP. In which I am fetching data from mysql in input fields and then carrying out basi arithmetic operations. 
I am using following code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$(document).on('keydown', '.username', function() {

var id = this.id;
var splitid = id.split('_');
var index = splitid[1];

$( '#'+id ).autocomplete({
source: function( request, response ) {
$.ajax({
url: "getDetails.php",
type: 'post',
dataType: "json",
data: {
search: request.term,request:1
},
success: function( data ) {
response( data );
}
});
},
select: function (event, ui) {
$(this).val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
var userid = ui.item.value; // selected id to input

                            // AJAX
$.ajax({
url: 'getDetails.php',
type: 'post',
data: {userid:userid,request:2},
dataType: 'json',
success:function(response){

var len = response.length;

if(len > 0){
 var id = response[0]['id'];
 var price = response[0]['price'];

                                        document.getElementById('price_'+index).value = price;
                                    }

                                }
                            });

                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                });

            });

        </script>

<script>
   $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('input.amount').keyup(function(){   
    var price = $("#price").val();
    var qty = $("#qty").val();
    var tax = $("#taxa").val();
    var disc = $("#disca").val();
    var total = $("#total").val();
      var total = (parseFloat(price) * parseFloat(qty)) + (parseFloat(tax) - parseFloat(disc));
    $("#total").val(parseFloat(total));
   });
});
</script>
  <td width="7%">Item Name</td>
    <td width="16%"><input type="text" name="item" style="height:35px;border:groove;width:200px;" /></td>
    <td width="3%">Qty.</td>
    <td width="7%"><input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" style="height:35px;border:groove;width:70px;"  class="amount"/></td>
    <td width="3%">Price</td>
    <td width="7%"><input type="text" name="price" id="price" style="height:35px;border:groove;width:80px;"  class="amount"/></td>
    <td width="4%">Tax</td>
    <td width="7%"><select name="tax"  style="height:35px;border:groove;width:80px;"></select></td>
    <td width="5%">Tax Amt.</td>
    <td width="7%"><input type="text" id="taxa" name="taxAmmount" style="height:35px;border:groove;width:80px;"  class="amount" /></td>
    <td width="4%">Disc. %</td>
    <td width="6%"><input type="text"  name="disc" style="height:35px;border:groove;width:70px;" /></td>
    <td width="6%">Disc. Amt.</td>
    <td width="7%"><input type="text" id="disca" name="discAmmount" style="height:35px;border:groove;width:80px;"  class="amount" /></td>
    <td width="3%">Total</td>
    <td width="8%"><input type="text" id="total" name="total" style="height:35px;border:groove;width:80px;"  class="amount" /></td>
```

getDetails.php

```
<?php
include "config.php";

$request = $_POST['request'];   // request

// Get username list
if($request == 1){
$search = $_POST['search'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM item WHERE itemName like'%".$search."%'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
$response[] = array("value"=>$row['id'],"label"=>$row['itemName']);
}

    // encoding array to json format
echo json_encode($response);
exit;
}

// Get details
if($request == 2){
$userid = $_POST['userid'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM item WHERE id=".$userid;

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$users_arr = array();

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
$userid = $row['id'];
$price = $row['salePrice'];
$users_arr[] = array("id" => $userid, "price" => $price,  );
 }

    // encoding array to json format
echo json_encode($users_arr);
exit;
}
```

What is the error ? Actually I grabbed two codes from the internet and put them together they both are working fine individually but when I put them together they don't work. 
Please help I am a beginner programmer, please help me to learn . Thanks

Comment: Please post your complete page

Comment: updated @B.Mossavari

Comment: first code is not a valid HTML please update it so we can actually test it